# Rendering a video sequence does not Display

Tags: rendering, video

I am using Blender to edit my videos, and I've run into a snag. Whenever I try to render the animation, It will only display as black.

My .blend data:
https://www.mediafire.com/?cb9u9lyzzj3mu2f

Does anyone know what's the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you go under the render tab, go down under post-processing and un-check the compositing pipeline and select the sequencing pipeline. Then try.